# I try to deploy my Yeoman AngularJS static site to Github pages but the git subtree command always gets rejected

Tags: angularjs, github, yeoman, github-pages, git-subtree

I am trying to deploy my AngularJS static site (which I began with Yeoman) as a Github page and was following the steps provided in the [Yeoman deployment guide](http://yeoman.io/deployment.html). I succeed in steps 1 and 2 but when I arrive at step 3, things go bad. Step 3 tells me to run

```
git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages
```

When I run this is what I see

```
$ git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages
git push using:  origin gh-pages
To git@github.com:siddhion/maxmythic_angular.git
 ! [rejected]        5db3233d7c0822eedc5500409ce6a2d4b73ad427 -> gh-pages (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:siddhion/maxmythic_angular.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and merge the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

I then I follow the hint and try

```
$ git pull origin master
From github.com:siddhion/maxmythic_angular
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
```

and then tried `git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages` again but got the same error as before.

At the Yeoman deployment page I see under the **Some common errors** section

> You might get an error like this Updates were rejected because the tip
>   of your current branch is behind. You can solve this by force pushing
>   to the remote (be careful though, it will destroy whatever is already
>   there).

I am apprehensive to force the `subtree push` because I am new to git in general and not sure what is going to be destroyed. I mean, I currently do not have a `gh-pages` branch at my maxmythic_angular `origin` remote so I am not worried about that but I have my `master`, `gh-pages-old` and `gh-pages-v1` branches there. Will they be destroyed if I run `git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages`?

### UPDATE

I went ahead and copied my work to another folder to be safe and I added `--force` to my `git subtree push` command and ran it. This is what I got

```
$ git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages --force
error: unknown option `force'
usage: git subtree add   --prefix=<prefix> <commit>
   or: git subtree add   --prefix=<prefix> <repository> <commit>
   or: git subtree merge --prefix=<prefix> <commit>
   or: git subtree pull  --prefix=<prefix> <repository> <refspec...>
   or: git subtree push  --prefix=<prefix> <repository> <refspec...>
   or: git subtree split --prefix=<prefix> <commit...>

    -h, --help            show the help
    -q                    quiet
    -d                    show debug messages
    -P, --prefix ...      the name of the subdir to split out
    -m, --message ...     use the given message as the commit message for the merge commit

options for 'split'
    --annotate ...        add a prefix to commit message of new commits
    -b, --branch ...      create a new branch from the split subtree
    --ignore-joins        ignore prior --rejoin commits
    --onto ...            try connecting new tree to an existing one
    --rejoin              merge the new branch back into HEAD

options for 'add', 'merge', 'pull' and 'push'
    --squash              merge subtree changes as a single commit
```

**How can I get the** `git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages` **command to work so I can deploy my site to gh-pages?**

### UPDATE

I wanted to see if this issue was to do with the instructions or just something fishy with my repo so I set up a new Angular app with `yo angular` and followed the deployment instructions. `git subtree push` worked this time. I still have no idea what happened to the gh-pages repo of mine. I will have to really learn `git` in and out.

Comment: did you try `git pull origin gh-pages`?

Comment: I just tried `git pull origin gh-pages` and it returned `From github.com:siddhion/maxmythic_angular
 * branch            gh-pages   -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.` Then I tried the full `git subtree` command again and it resulted in same error as I stated before.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The problem was that I had dist already committed in the current repo. No as a subtree. The following steps should resolve the issue

```
// remove the dist and commit
rd  /s dist
git commit -am "remove dist folder"
// add the subtree and push
git subtree add --prefix dist origin gh-pages
git subtree push --prefix dist origin gh-pages
```

That seemed to do the trick for me

Answer (score 0):

I also used the subtree method for a while to push the typical Yeoman dist folder to a remote (in my case gh-pages). It's a make do but causes headaches when something gets changed on the server.
You then have to resort to much less elegant solutions which you describe above. And those create even more hassle, as you noticed.I believe for this particular workflow, using the subtree method is hack.

There's a much better solution to this: [grunt-build-control](https://github.com/robwierzbowski/grunt-build-control) by Rob Wierzbowski. Takes 10 mins to install but works like a charm and the whole deploying of the build folder to remotes becomes automatic. Completely version controlled and painless.

Its now also mentioned in the [Yeoman wiki](https://github.com/yeoman/yeoman/wiki/Deployment).